# Find the control function

Tags: control-theory

Determine the general form of $u_0, u_1 ~\text{and} ~ u_2$ if a system of difference equations of the form

$$x_{n+1} = Ax_n  + Bu_n,$$

where:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 2 & 2  \\
  -1 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}$$

and:

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}$$

is to be controlled for $x_0 = 0 ~ to ~ x_3 = [2, 1, 2]^T$ .

Comment: Thanks @Amzoti do you think you can haelp with the question. I have calculated the control martix $$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 6 & 6 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -3 & -2 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Later would be great thanks so much @Amzoti would really appreciate any help you could give me

Comment: Hi @Amzoti did you manage to get a chance to look at the question?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes I think I managed to solve it for myself by taking the Taylor series for cosh and sinh and substituting in. Thank you for your help on this one very much appreciated

Comment: Hi @Amzoti have you attempted this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The controllability matrix is
$$
C=\begin{pmatrix}
B,AB,A^2B
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&2&2&6&6\\
0&1&-1&0&-3&-2\\
1&0&1&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Clearly it has full rank. Thus the system is always controllable. In fact, if you take $u_0=0,\,u_1=(1,0)^T$ and $u_2=(1,2)^T$, you can get $x_3$ from $x_0$. For the general form of $u_0=(a,b)^T, u_1=(c,d)^T, u_2=(e,f)^T$, solve the system of linear equations $Cv=(2,1,2)^T$, where $v=(a,b,c,d,e,f)^T$.

Comment: Apologies @user1551 I realised I typed the B matrix wrong. I have edited it now. It should make more sense, Thanks for all your help

Comment: hi @user1551 thanks for this, could you expand on how you got went from the general form to the u values. Im can't quite make the link between your 3 equations for Cv=(2 1 2)^T and those

Comment: @Amzoti Im still struggling to see how to get from the controlability matrix to the solution? If you have the time I would be greatful if you could explain? Thank you so much, going round in circles here

Comment: @Jay As $x_0=0$, we have $x_1=Bu_0$ and in turn $x_2=ABu_0+Bu_1$ and $x_3=A^2Bu_0+ABu_1+Bu_2$, which is equivalent to $x_3=Cv$ if you stack up $u_0,u_1$ and $u_2$ together to form a $6$-vector $v$. That's why you need to solve $Cv=(2,1,2)^T$ for a general solution. I haven't solved it in my answer, as I thought you should know enough linear algebra to solve it.

Comment: @user1551 I think Im missing something. I have 6 unknowns (a,b,c,d,e,f) with only 3 equations? 2c+2d+6e+6f=2 , b-c-3e-2f=1 and a+c+e=2? SHould i be able to solve from this?

Comment: @Jay Yes, why not? You do remember elementary row operations, row echelon form, etc., don't you? Solving systems of linear equations is a standard topic in virtually every introductory textbook on linear algebra. If you have forgotten how to solve them, you may read your textbook again.

Comment: Can you confirm that I those equations are correct above?@User1551

Comment: @Jay Yes, they are.

Comment: @user1551 I have reduced the system to augmented echelon form to get   $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -2  & -3 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3  & 3 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
so there are infinitely many solutions. however I still dont understand how you achieved the u_0 u_1 and u_2 you have given specific for x_3

Comment: @Jay Of course there are infinitely many solutions. (Weren't you asked to find the *general* solution for the $u_i$s?) Now you have reduced the system to a row echelon form, you can write down the solutions immediately.

Answer (score 0):

@user1551 do you agree with  the general form of $ u_0 u_1 $and $ u_2 $ is

$ u_0 =(1-3r_3 +2r_2 +r_1, 2-r_1 -r_3)^T 
u_1 = (1-3r_3 -3r_2 -r_1, r_1)^T
u_2=(r_2, r_3)^T $